# How DLLs are shared among applications?

Tags: dll

I am under the impression that DLLs are mapped into the address space of the calling process. If that is the case, how DLLs can be shared among other processes?

Regards,
Arun

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways:

1) Common library code is put in DLL files (it stands for Dynamic-Link Library), so that common portions of code uses less space on HDD (and are easier to update).

2) In-memory sharing (copy-on-write scheme, when pages that are common to several processes are mapped to the same physical page).